# BDDMockito call real static mocked method

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

With BDDMockito I mocked static methods. Now I want to use real method of ResourceHelper in the answer method. As I understand, this answer method will call himself. So how to call real static method?

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(SomeHelper.class);
BDDMockito.given(SomeHelper.helpMethod(Matchers.eq(SomeClass.class), Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString())).willAnswer(newAnswer<String>() {     

        @Override
        public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            //Here I want call real ResourceHelper's method
            return SomeHelper.helpMethod(AnotherClass.class, "param1", "param2");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use `BDDMockito.willCallRealMethod()`.
To do so, replace your current stubbing code with the following:

```
given(SomeHelper.helpMethod(Matchers.eq(SomeClass.class), Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString())).willCallRealMethod();
```

This delegates to the `doCallRealMethod()` method of standard Mockito.